# From txt file to list - Python

Tags: python

input: data.txt looks like this

```
122.2 124.2 124.3 125.6 126.3 126.5 126.5 127.2 127.3
127.5 127.9 128.6 128.8 129.0 129.2 129.4 129.6 130.2
130.4 130.8 131.3 131.4 131.4 131.5 131.6 131.6 131.8
131.8 132.3 132.4 132.4 132.5 132.5 132.5 132.5 132.6
132.7 132.9 133.0 133.1 133.1 133.1 133.1 133.2 133.2
133.2 133.3 133.3 133.5 133.5 133.5 133.8 133.9 134.0
134.0 134.0 134.0 134.1 134.2 134.3 134.4 134.4 134.6
134.7 134.7 134.7 134.8 134.8 134.8 134.9 134.9 135.2
135.2 135.2 135.3 135.3 135.4 135.5 135.5 135.6 135.6
135.7 135.8 135.8 135.8 135.8 135.8 135.9 135.9 135.9
135.9 136.0 136.0 136.1 136.2 136.2 136.3 136.4 136.4
136.6 136.8 136.9 136.9 137.0 137.1 137.2 137.6 137.6
137.8 137.8 137.8 137.9 137.9 138.2 138.2 138.3 138.3
138.4 138.4 138.4 138.5 138.5 138.6 138.7 138.7 139.0
139.1 139.5 139.6 139.8 139.8 140.0 140.0 140.7 140.7
140.9 140.9 141.2 141.4 141.5 141.6 142.9 143.4 143.5
143.6 143.8 143.8 143.9 144.1 144.5 144.5 147.7 147.7
```

necessary output:

I would like to import all of this into a single list using python and IDE Spyder.

```py
List1 = [122.2, 124.2, 124.3, ..., 147.7]
```

Comment: Okay, cool. Do you have a question? What part of this do you already know how to do? Can you open a file? Can you split strings?

Comment: There are many examples on the Internet explaining how you can parse files with Python. This is a trivial task, so you better check some tutorials out there.

Comment: Look into [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for how to open and read from files. Then, you can look into string parsing and splitting techniques to make it a list. Don't forget to convert the strings into floats so you can parse them. Have a good day!

Comment: Note that Spyder has nothing to do with this. Separate your editor from your code in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that your inputs will consistently look as your `data.txt` file does. i.e. single space (" ") separated values, then you could do the below, making use of the standard `csv` library.

```py
import csv

# Create a list to store your loaded terms
terms = []

# Load the file
with open("data.txt", "r") as fh:
    # Assumes your file has a " " (delimiter) 
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter = " ")

    # Loop through each row in the file

    for row in reader:
        terms += row
```

Answer (score -1):

First, use [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to access your file. It is best to wrap it in a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to ensure the file is closed after.

Then, the file can be iterated over to access each line.

Finally, call [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on each line to separate it into parts delimited by whitespace. This can be done in a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to obtain a single list as the result.

Putting it all together:

```py
with open('data.txt') as f:
    list1 = [part for line in f for part in line.split()]
print(list1)
```